# Numpy array views syntax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I think I understand the basics of numpy array views (it doesn't copy data and we're basically referring to the same data buffer as the array but with different offsets, etc.). I am however confused about the syntax.

What I do understand is that if I were to run this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_sample((100,100))
b = a[:10, :10]
```

Then `b` would be the first 10 rows and the first 10 columns of `a`.

What I don't understand is what `a[::10]` does. Could someone please explain that?

Also - are there any other similar things I should know about when dealing with numpy arrays?

I've looked at array views on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html but it doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::10` syntax means sample the entire range returning every ten elements.  SO if you wanted to return 1/100th of the data (ie every 10th row, every 10th column), you'd do:

```
b = a[::10, ::10]
```

`a[::10]` is just shorthand for `a[::10, ::]` if I recall.

Comment: isn't that 1/100th of the data?

Comment: okay... so what does `a[:2:10, :2:10]` do? it returns something when I try it out on IDLE?

Comment: What is the shape of the resulting array?  I don't have access to python right now to test it.  And is it any different than `a[2:10, 2:10]`

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out the syntax is `array[start:end:steps, start:end:steps,..]` for as many dimensions as I have. So basically in the example I gave with the shape being (100,100), `a[::10, ::10] == a[:100:10, :100:10]`

Comment: Interesting.  Admittedly, I usually get tripped up with indexing in numpy and only choose to remember a subset of use cases.  I've never run into any trouble with using the :: syntax exclusively.